# multiple table join error, with expected

Tags: sql

Error:

``with'' expected but identifier indv found: indv join com

Code:

```
select temp.CAND_NAME, count(*)
from 
(
indv join com
on indv.OTHER_ID = com.CMTE_ID

 join can

on indv.CMTE_ID = can.CAND_PCC) as temp

group by temp.CAND_ID
having temp.CAND_ID = "P00003392" or 
temp.CAND_ID = "P60006111" or 
temp.CAND_ID = "P60007168" or temp.CAND_ID = "P80001571"
```

What could be wrong?

What I'm doing:

I have three tables:

indv, com, and can.

I want to join all three, and query can.CAND_NAME as well as count(*)

How do I want to join?

2 things:

1. indv.OTHER_ID = com._CMTE_ID
2. indv.CMTE_ID = can.CAND_PCC

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with your query. What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Results you don't expect.

Comment: The error message is the first 2 lines of my question. I'm using spark Dataframes, for which I can use SQL directly. So everything is in sql.sql("""........................""")

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses and alias are not correct.  I would write this as:

```
select CAND_NAME, count(*)
from indv join
     com
     on indv.OTHER_ID = com.CMTE_ID join
     can
     on indv.CMTE_ID = can.CAND_PCC
where CAND_ID IN ('P00003392', 'P60006111', 'P60007168, 'P80001571')
group by CAND_ID;
```

Notes:

- The parentheses with the table alias are not correct.
- You should use appropriate table names for the columns.  I don't know what they are.
- It is better to filter *before* the `group by` using `where`, rather than afterwards using `having`.
- It is better to use `in` rather than a bunch of `or` expressions.

Comment: This doesn't quite work - It tells me"u"Reference 'CAND_ID' is ambiguous, could be: CAND_ID#14, CAND_ID#90.;"
" But thanks for the other suggestions.

Comment: @Jobs . . . You just need to specify the table that it is coming from, I think.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. I like your indentation and style - easy to read and concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this as:

```
SELECT cn.CAND_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM indv i
INNER JOIN com cm
    ON i.OTHER_ID = cm.CMTE_ID
INNER JOIN can cn
    ON cn.i.CMTE_ID = cn.CAND_PCC
WHERE
    cn.CAND_ID IN ('P00003392', 'P60006111', 'P60007168', 'P80001571')
GROUP BY
    cn.CAND_ID, cn.CAND_NAME
```

- The multiple `OR` conditions can be written as `IN`.
- Use a meaningful alias to improve readability.
- If you're using other rdbms except for MySQL, you need to put non-aggregate columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
SELECT can.CAND_NAME,COUNT(*)
FROM indv inner join com
on indv.OTHER_ID=com._CMTE_ID
inner join can 
on indv.CMTE_ID=com.CAND_PCC
WHERE CAND_ID IN ('P00003392', 'P60006111', 'P60007168, 'P80001571')
group by can.CAND_NAME
```

User 'IN' instead of 'OR' . This should be work as you expected.

Comment: please mark correct answer for let others which is right